# Could I open a URL attaching clipboard text?

Tags: javascript, url, browser, clipboard, copy-paste

Maybe there's an easy solution to this, but I couldn't come up with it.

I have a software that lets me associate actions to a mouse gesture, and in order to describe those actions you need to write them in Javascript. The action could be performed either in a specific context (in this case, a CAT Tool programme) or anytime I do that mouse gesture (a so-called "global action").

The action I need is to open a URL to perform a search, and the term to be searched is defined by my selection, which will be copied to the clipboard, and then pasted to the URL.

For example, if I select the word "banana", I want the Javascript code to take me to this particular URL:

https://www.google.com/search?q=banana

The URL will change depending on what text I select, so "https://www.google.com/search?q=" will be fixed and "banana" is acting as a variable.

What I have done so far is to make the browser open a window (say, Google for example) and then type what's written on the clipboard, but I want to make the process faster by having that input written onto the URL itself as a variable.

Comment: `the term to be searched is defined by my selection` - if you are selecting text on a web page that you control then no problem, you can just add script to your page.  If you wanted to select text on a page you do NOT control then you'd need something like a browser extension to do this.  So the approach depends on where you want to select text from.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your help and sorry for the lack of context! I have edited the question. In this case the text could be in theory selected anywhere and then trigger the action described by Javascript with that software (strokesplus).

Comment: But if you are writing the action in javascript, then the forwarding to the URL bit should happen there and you have access to the selected text there? If you don't, then you can't... Its pretty simple tbh. If you are currently in control of copying to the clipboard, you could also you construct a URL and open it instead of copying it. Otherwise, no, I don't see how you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the answer! I just needed to concatenate clip.GetText to the desired URL :-). For example:

```
sp.SendModifiedVKeys([vk.LCONTROL], [vk.VK_C])
var QURL="google.com/search?q=" + clip.GetText()
sp.RunProgram(QURL, "", "open", "normal", true, false, false);
```

Comment: If you share the working code piece would be helpful.

Comment: sp.SendModifiedVKeys([vk.LCONTROL], [vk.VK_C]);
var QURL2="https://www.google.com/search?q=" + clip.GetText();
sp.RunProgram(QURL2, "", "open", "normal", true, false, false);

Comment: Edit your answer and add it there. Comments are not readable.